# Why exceptions in PHP for MySQLi

Tags: php, exception, mysqli, wrapper, error-code

I've heard that you should use exceptions in PHP code when handling with mysqli instead of the mysql(i) error codes.

So I began to make an own wrapper for mysqli objects which should translate all error codes to own exceptions according to the error message. Regarding the big amount of possible error codes and the fact you have to cover all mysqli methods with `if... else..` in own methods, I began to doubt if it is really necessary.

In most cases a little wrapper catching the most usual error codes and offering the most used functions would be enough, but nevertheless it's not complete and not really safe at all (i. e. when you don't catch some error codes you forgot).

And handling the error codes with if/else and mysqli_connect_errno (or sth. like that) is quite the same as handling them with `try ... catch ConnectionNotEstablishedException $e` ... .

So why is it useful to wrap mysqli objects into an own database object translating the error codes into exceptions?

Yours,
Greeny

Comment: use mysqli_sql_exception - you don't need to write your own wrapper

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's a best-practice principle and essential in the modern MVC developing structure.

Some advantages this will give you is that your development team will spend less time debugging, because Exceptions that you defined in your wrap will be more detailed and clear about some malfunction than the standard mysql errors would give.

Secondly (which you actually already said yourself), Exceptions can be caught, errors can't, which means another productivity improvement for your development.

Answer (score 0):

> Why exceptions in PHP for MySQLi

is one question.

> why is it useful to wrap mysqli objects into an own database object translating the error codes into exceptions?

is another

> why is it useful to wrap mysqli objects into an own database object

again is a different one.

> translate all error codes to own exceptions according to the error message.

is the only real question actually.

Having them all mixed in your head into one, you will never get a satisfactory answer.

what you have to understand first - there are no self-sufficient goals. Every action have to be taken not because "someone said so" but because *you* need it. If you don't need it - better leave it alone.

So it goes for the specific exceptions. You need one only if you have certain scenario to handle. Say, you want to catch "Duplicate key" error. Because you have some code to run in case of it. If so - then go on with `DuplicateKeyException`. Means you can always wrap a database operation in a try..catch and catch this very specific exception. While all other exceptions will not be caught and bubble up. An obvious advantage of such an approach - you always know which exceptions you need to create.

But in case you have no scenario other than just log an error - then you don't need specific exceptions at all. Which makes your task dramatically easier. Just because mysqli is able to throw exceptions by itself - so, you don't need neither to throw any specific exception, nor catch it.